# Should I use a PictureBox or a Panel to draw on my Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panel, picturebox

Is there a recommended one to use in order to add lines and circles, so I can build a graph?
I will possibly work with background images under the graph itself.

Comment: Also, are you using WPF, or Silverlight?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I assume it's just Windows Forms based on the tags.

Comment: I'd say neither. If you're doing your own drawing, just inherit from `Control` itself unless you have a need specifically for one of the other two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `PictureBox` - it'll be easiest to maintain the code later on. A `Panel` is not really useful in this case and drawing directly on the `Form` - while it'd work - would make it harder to make changes later on.

Just handle the `Paint` event of the `PictureBox` and do all your drawing in there.

Comment: also noticed that animated graphic shapes are flickering on a `panel` and on `picturebox` it does not happen.

Comment: @jonathana You can make it work the right way even with a Panel but it's extra work that you don't have to do with a PictureBox.